# Full, 2-way table synchronization

Tags: algorithms, database, synchronization, data-replication

I need to synchronize tables of data between two different systems. This is a multi-master setup; data can get changed in either system. After a synchronization runs I'd like the data in each table to be the same.

I'm having a tough time coming up with an algorithm for sending only incremental changes from one system to another. Here's my current algorithm:

1. In the local system make a list of the ids of the records that have changed since the last run.
2. Import all changed records from the remote system, and update the "modified" timestamp of each record locally.
3. Export to the remote system the list of records with the ids from step 1.

This works, but gets cumbersome when there are potentially millions of records to exchange. The list of ids can't be stored in memory without possible out-of-memory errors.

The reason I have to make the list of ids is that if I run an import first, the "modified" timestamp column will get updated locally, and then I'll lose the knowledge of which records have been changed since the last run and need to be exported.

Another way to do it would be to mark all of the records that need to be exported before the run starts. The problem with that is that it means setting a flag in millions of records, which is going to be very slow. (I'm using Postgres, which does not support in-place updates.)

Yet another way to do it would be to refrain from updating the modified timestamp when you do the import in step #2. The problem there is that I really need that timestamp updated if the record has changed, because I am synchronizing the local table against potentially more than one remote system.

Obviously, the best way to do this would be to use some kind of Change Data Capture stream that produces a log of the changes each table has seen, but that is not available in this situation.

(Let's leave aside conflict resolution for the moment. For each column in the table I can designate the "owner" of the column, either system A or system B, so that the owner can always overwrite the column without a conflict.)

Question: is there a better algorithm for this? What are the common solutions to this problem?

**Update**

In response to the comments: I'm synchronizing a local CRM, with a list of contacts, with various external apps that have APIs. For example, my local list of sales leads needs to get exported to Mailchimp, and any leads that come in through Mailchimp (say, through a web form) need to get added back to the CRM. Incremental changes in the CRM (say, a change to name, address, or email) would need to get pushed to Mailchimp, and incremental email status changes (say, bounces or unsubscribes) would need to get sync'd back to the CRM.

Also -- the CRM will have to get sync'd with more than one external service. Contacts will have to get sent to Facebook for advertising, or potentially some call center app.

I can make the simplifying assumption that certain apps "own" certain fields. For example, the CRM can own name and address, and Mailchimp can own email_unsubscribed or email_bounced. Field-level conflicts can be resolved by letting the owning app get its way.

Yes, I understand that multi-master setups are difficult, but for this application it's really not optional.

Comment: What's your research on Event Sourcing and CQRS, and how/whether would those fit into your design?

Comment: *"multi-master setup"* - well there's your problem. From what you describe, rather than the whole table having one machine as master, it is the rows themselves that have a master (an "owner"), and each machine's local table consists firstly of the rows over which it is master, and secondly the rows for which it provides a local cache for a variety of other masters, and which all has an eventual-consistency style setup. Have you considered whether this reflects a fundamental design error? The chances of this kind of design operating reliably are effectively zero.

Comment: @Steve well, database clusters do exactly this. Though, i agree that its extremly hard to get right. And why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @marstato, and NASA goes exactly to the moon. It's not just the fiendish subtlety of the synchronisation algorithm, it's the ability of developers and users to reason about how the machine works, in order that they can control it sensibly to achieve their purpose. Explaining to a user that edits on some records are guaranteed to apply (when it's a local master), whereas other edits can be pre-empted later (where an edit on a slave is overwritten by an earlier edit on the master, which hadn't propagated to the slave)... (1/2)

Comment: turns the dial from 1 all the way up to 11 in terms of requirements for training, documentation, and gumption on the part of users and developers. Once you add in automatic reporting and feedback loops, where business activities (some of which may be beyond the scope of the machine itself, and not within the knowledge of the developer who wrote it) may have already been triggered to happen in the interstitial period when the system was not fully consistent, things can appear to start going haywire. Eventual consistency is a spell cast far too often by the sorcerer's apprentice. (2/2)

Comment: @marstato, just to be clear as well, I can't speak for other technologies, but my understanding of "clustering" in SQL products doesn't involve any relaxation of transactional consistency for ordinary DML operations. There is always just one master, and nothing is changed unless the master is changed. If a slave becomes disconnected from the master, it doesn't store up changes and attempt to synchronise later (with the risk of conflicts), rather the slave's ability to make changes ceases until its ability to coordinate changes with the master is restored.

Comment: @Steve Please see my update.

Comment: @ccleve, for something that sounds like it's at the scale of personal use, I would probably start by trying to analyse which fields are actually shared, and with whom. To perform the synchronisation, you pull in the list of changes from all APIs treating these as proposed changes (retaining information about the source of every such proposed change), you apply an algorithm which resolves any conflicts (by preferring the "owner" of that field if a conflict arises between two proposed changes), and then you distribute the changed value immediately to all others except the source of the change.

Comment: In other words, as a result of the analysis you should end up with structured metadata which identifies each field which exists in more than one system (and is thus subject to synchronisation in principle), identifies the set of systems which actually share that field, identifies the name of that field in each system, and identifies which system has "ownership" of that field. Treat your personal CRM on an equal footing as the external APIs for this purpose. An unanswered question might be what happens when two non-owners propose conflicting changes, if that is possible to arise.

Comment: @Steve This isn't personal in nature. It's likely to have thousands of users in the not-too-distant future, and it already handles millions of records (which are not sync'd with Mailchimp, but with external consumer data vendors.) The issue here isn't fields; it's with deciding which rows to sync and how to track them in an batch processing system. Using the "modified" timestamp doesn't work for the reasons I discussed. Pulling "proposed" changes into a temporary table and analyzing them might work; I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @ccleve, is it possible to get a definitive list of changes/audit trail from each system, at the granularity of the *field* (not the row)? Or at least, to extract all data and keep a complete versioned mirror of the target systems (which you can further analyse to identify exactly which fields have changed between versions)? In the latter case, it becomes a case of pull in a new mirror version from each target, compare each new mirror to the last to identify field-level changes for that target - you now have your "proposed changes", for piping along to the conflict resolution step. (1/2)

Comment: To push changes back out, you modify the mirrors (so you keep your last mirror copy consistent), then synchronise the changes from the mirrors back out to the targets, checking that nothing has changed since the mirror was first pulled in. The targets must support some facility for you to check that nothing has changed, and to apply the changes transactionally. Otherwise there is a risk of inconsistency and data loss if changes occur after you fetch but before you update (which can't be solved purely by yourself - the target APIs must be designed to participate in transactional updates). (2/2)

Comment: @Steve This is possible. I did consider maintaining a shadow copy of every remote data source and just doing diffs against the local table. This scheme would also handle deletes, which are a giant pain unless you've got a Change Data Capture log. But that sure is a lot of data to store and maintain. There's probably no good answer to this problem.

Comment: The two fundamental requirements of the *external APIs* here are firstly whether you can detect changes on the target at the field level *somehow*, and secondly whether your changes can be committed transactionally somehow. If these requirements cannot be met, then the idea is simply impossible to implement without a risk of data loss, because there exists a potential of conflict not just between the various target systems, but between you and your users on each target system (if they update their data between you checking for updates on a target, and pushing out an update to that target).1/2

Comment: To put it another way @ccleve, the target API must be capable of resolving a different kind of conflict. That which arises when you check for changes on the target, their user then updates the data on the target (obsoleting the check you just made), and you then attempt to impose a change on the target based on using your old, obsolete, check which took no account of the change made by the user since. Only the target can provide that facility - there is no algorithmic solution that you can implement unilaterally. (2/2)

Comment: *gets cumbersome when there are potentially millions of records to exchange* Seems to me the easy fix for this sort of problem is to  run the synchronization more often. Instead of running in large batches, you could run the job in near-real-time, i.e. every few seconds or minutes, and capture only a few changes at a time. Is this an option?

Comment: @Steve if you shard a table, different nodes in the cluster become the master for a (deterministically and easily determinable) subset of all possible rows. If you connect to a slave and send an update, it will apply it to its local shard and forward to the other nodes so these can apply the update to their data as well. That can happen transparently to the user - you just send the `UPDATE` DML to whatever node you want. As for training and headscratching: not unless it is very clearly visible which rows are local-master. Better even if any given node disallows changes to local copies.

Comment: @marstato, is such sharding employing eventual consistency and resolving conflicts, or does it just hold the user waiting whilst a so-called "distributed transaction" is concluded (and which requires the shard-master to be online and fully available, or else the transaction would abort)? In the latter case, even thought it would seem there are multiple machines involved, they are actually yoked into one fully-cooperative system (and everything is designed as such), and it is the assembled system as a whole which is the only real master.

Comment: @Steve i've only seen the second in an actual database product. Yes, it only works because the entire cluster appears as one system and by sacrificing some ACID properties. Though i've also worked on a system where there were multiple masters (as in systems operated by entirely separate companies with different software and varying data models). It worked well because a) the sharding key was very simple and obvious and b) each master only allowed edits of the records it owned.

Comment: @marstato, that's really what my question is getting at - are there any sacrifices of ACID properties? And if so, then which ones? There is hardly any organisation in which it is acceptable by design for the machines to silently lose or corrupt ordinary business records.

Comment: How do you detect that data is changed on the external app? Do you have access to its DB or do you need to poll the api to detect changes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar problem with only 2 data stores. I believe for each distinct master data store you need (# master stores - 1) intermediary stores to track "last known state" for consistency checks. In my case this means a single additional store.

The sync process then runs an export from A to B and an import from B to A. Order shouldn't matter I don't think, but there may be edge cases where doing one before the other would result in slightly different results. During the sync it utilizes the intermediary store to determine if properties were changed in A or B or both.

Determining individual property changes per record looks something like:

```
finalValue = sourceValue != intermediaryValue && intermediaryValue == targetValue ? sourceValue : targetValue

Update Target with finalValue
Update Intermediary Store with same updates made to target
```

So far that's how I'm approaching the problem. It assumes the "target wins" in cases where both sides have changed. So you could handle that differently depending which source you consider the winner in conflicts. Or throw an error for manual resolution. Or handle different properties conditionally depending on the source.

EDIT:

```
    public static string GetMediatedValue(string sourceValue,
string intermediaryValue,
string targetValue,
SyncConflictResolution resolution = SyncConflictResolution.SourceWins)
    {
        string finalTargetValue;

        if (sourceValue == intermediaryValue)
        {
            // no change or change in target
            finalTargetValue = targetValue;
        }
        else if (intermediaryValue == targetValue)
        {
            // no change or change in source
            finalTargetValue = sourceValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // change in both
            switch (resolution)
            {
                case SyncConflictResolution.SourceWins:
                    finalTargetValue = sourceValue;
                    break;
                case SyncConflictResolution.TargetWins:
                    finalTargetValue = targetValue;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Unable to resolve sync conflict: Source: {sourceValue} - Target: {targetValue}");
            }
        }


        return finalTargetValue;
    }
```

Example usage:

```
var source = GetSourceValue(id);
var target = GetTargetValue(otherId);
var intermediary = GetIntermediaryValue(id, otherId);// or whatever
var finalValue = GetMediatedValue(source, intermediary, target);

if(finalValue != source)
{
     // update source
}

if(finalValue != target)
{
     // update target
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the benefit of the intermediate table. Wouldn't it be identical to A at all times?

Comment: If you want to support changes in both A and B, the intermediate table captures a snapshot of the last known values. Then if property X is changed in both A and B within the same window, the intermediate table allows you to determine this and choose the outcome (A wins or B wins, or throw error for manual resolution, etc.) Without the intermediate table you have no way of knowing if property X is being overwritten by whichever sync runs "first", rather than the more deterministic "A wins/B wins" style resolution.

Comment: @Chad could you please elaborate on this solution? Perhaps a diagram for the flow or maybe you have source code? Sounds interesting, but I can't fully understand the picture